# Creating SVN Change Logs when there are multiple stages in the build

Tags: svn, jenkins, changelog

I have several projects in Jenkins that run sequentially. The first few jobs run when a change is made to the SVN Repository, and the final one runs on a set time schedule. Using the "svn log" command, I'd like to make a change report of the changes that reached the last step in the pipeline (there might be multiple revisions that contributed, since it runs on a time schedule). I know how to generate a change log in general, but I am unsure how to get only the revisions that reached the final step, excluding any that failed at some earlier step in the build.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to do your builds. Jenkins can execute a build when it detects a change in the Subversion repository, and then trigger other builds if you desire. Jenkins will show you the Subversion repository revision and a complete history of all the changes. You wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel.

Even better, Jenkins can take something built in one job, and then include that in another build. And, you can build *pipeline* jobs which allows you to view everything at once.

Jenkins will do exactly what you describe, and make it easy to access the information via webpages, and you won't have to reinvent the wheel to do it.

Jenkins is easy to setup and understand, and contains hundreds of plugins that can extend what Jenkins can do, and once you have it setup, you may do other things with Jenkins you haven't thought of.